# Increase PCM sample data size

Tags: android, mediaextractor

I've noticed when using `MediaExtractor` that since there is a lot more audio samples than video frames for a movie, using a One-Image-Decode/One-SoundSample-Decode/One-Image-Encode/OneSound-SoundSample-Encode is not a good strategy as it always ends up by having a lot more audio samples queued for the encoding.

Is this possible when using `MediaExtractor` to have a custom PCM sample size greater than 4096 bytes (or whatever the size is for the context)? 8192 would be great.

For:

```
int size = videoExtractor.ReadSampleData (decoderInputBuffer, 0);
```

Size will always be 4096.

It means that for a 44100, stereo, 16 bits, sound, this represents +- 23ms, which is more or less 43.5 audio samples per second for, sometime, 24 images per second. Doubling the sample size of PCM would allow the video to always have equally or more of audio ready for encoding. This would even allow me to maybe sync it at 24 fps and play the audio samples using `AudioTrack`, so it opens possibilities for a live preview of my rendering.

I've tried:

```
inputFormat.SetInteger (MediaFormat.KeyMaxInputSize, 8192);
```

But it looks more like an optimization setting to set the minimum internal buffer for the decoder.

Is the size customizable?

[EDIT]

For now, I encode two audio samples for each video frame when queuing and the performance change is not noticeable for the video encoding speed. As predicted this ends almost at the same time.

```
while (_shouldCopyAudio && encodeMoreAudioThanVideo++ < 2) {
    [...]
    audioEncoder.QueueInputBuffer (encoderInputBufferIndex, 0, size, 
    pcmChunk.PresentationTimeUs, (MediaCodecBufferFlags)pcmChunk.Flags);
```